# Range of Blast powers

Tags: gumshoe, mutant-city-blues

A number of the powers available to players in Mutant City Blues are designated as Blast powers, and can be used as ranged attacks. However, I can't find where it explains exactly what the range of these attacks is.

**What is the range of the different Blast powers in Mutant City Blues?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it.

> **General Powers**
>   If a power is described as ranged, but no specific range is given, that distance varies... with your current pool value in the ability. If it is 3 or less, your range is 25 meters. When your pool is between 4 and 6 it is 50 meters. If your pool is 7 or more, your range is one hundred meters. (*Mutant City Blues* 38)

This does make some plots impossible (e.g. skyscraper-perching laser assassins), but also makes investigation easier (e.g. "The assailant must have been within 100 meters to have killed him that way").